# An error in Blackberry during HttpConnection message contains Datagram(ConnectionBase).receive (Datagram) line 538

Tags: blackberry

This is my code where the connection problem occuring.
`HttpConnection` is not getting a response from an connection obj in a input stream. The occuring error is:

`Datagram(ConnectionBase).receive (Datagram)` line 538

```
 HttpConnection httpCon = null;
    InputStream iStream = null;
    String url = null;
    String result = "";
    public GetXmlHttp(String str)
    {
        url=str;
    }
    public String RESULT()
    {       
        try
        {   
            httpCon = (HttpConnection)Connector.open(url);
            httpCon.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.GET);
            iStream = httpCon.openInputStream();//error is here

            int httpResponse = httpCon.getResponseCode();
            System.out.println("httpResponse code"+httpResponse);
            System.out.println(httpResponse);
            if(httpResponse != 200)
            return null;

            InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(iStream);
            StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer();
            char[] ch=new char[1020];
            while(in.read(ch)!=-1)
            {
                sb.append(ch);
            }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Posting the exception would help, but allso have a look at the API documentation for HttpConnection. There is sample code posted there for getting via an HttpConnection which has at least one significant difference from yours. getResponseCode is called before openInputStream:

```
void getViaHttpConnection(String url) throws IOException {
     HttpConnection c = null;
     InputStream is = null;
     int rc;

     try {
         c = (HttpConnection)Connector.open(url);

         // Getting the response code will open the connection,
         // send the request, and read the HTTP response headers.
         // The headers are stored until requested.
         rc = c.getResponseCode();
         if (rc != HttpConnection.HTTP_OK) {
             throw new IOException("HTTP response code: " + rc);
         }

         is = c.openInputStream();
```